# How to select results from a table based on user input and display them?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, client-side

Let's say I'm creating a product recommender, e.g to recommend a good laptop to buy (from a small number of possibilities). The user selects specific options (such as "$300-$400" or "Windows 8") and the page should automatically display the relevant results to the user. Obviously, one could query a mySQL database for the information, but it seems for a small amount of data it would be better to do everything on the client-side.

What's a good way to store data on the client side so that it would be easy to select the relevant data and display it with javascript?

Comment: Not sure what you mean `good way to do it all the client-side`.  Can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Have you look into [jquery datatables](http://http://datatables.net/)?

Comment: @peterpan, thanks i'll look at it. If it can display results based on specific queries, it should do the trick.

Comment: If you have a database already, isn't it the simplest way to just make a query for the DB, instead of storing some parts of it into client's machine?

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-store-data-in-dom/

maybe jquery.data() can help ... it storex values in the dom elements

Comment: @Teemu, i'll just have a table of data of about 30 elements, so a whole server-side database seems a bit much